# Can't Determine Cause of Shutdown of Ubuntu Server 21.10

Tags: server, shutdown

I've done my best to look around at other threads, but can't seem to figure this one out.

I've freshly installed Ubuntu Server 21.10 on my home server machine, which is made up of some older hardware (which I intend to begin replacing if it sounds like it might be a hardware issue). Post installation, the only thing I've done is installed docker to run some containers for my home media use (plex, reverse proxy, unifi controller, etc.).

Everything seems to run just fine, but I've had ~5 or so unexpected reboot since yesterday when I installed everything. Funny enough, now I'm at 18 hours of uptime and perplexed at what was causing the initial reboots.

Here is the output from the `last` command:

```
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-22-generi Wed Dec 29 02:28   still running
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-22-generi Tue Dec 28 18:05   still running
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-22-generi Tue Dec 28 18:02 - 18:05  (00:02)
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-22-generi Tue Dec 28 14:19 - 18:05  (03:46)
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-22-generi Tue Dec 28 14:17 - 18:05  (03:47)
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-22-generi Tue Dec 28 12:31 - 18:05  (05:34)
ben      pts/1        192.168.1.100    Mon Dec 27 22:33 - 04:18  (05:45)
ben      pts/0        192.168.1.100    Mon Dec 27 21:54 - 00:18  (02:24)
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-22-generi Mon Dec 27 21:53 - 18:05  (20:12)
ben      pts/0        192.168.1.100    Mon Dec 27 21:32 - 21:53  (00:21)
ben      tty1                          Mon Dec 27 21:28 - down   (00:25)
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-22-generi Mon Dec 27 21:27 - 21:53  (00:25)
ben      tty1                          Mon Dec 27 21:13 - down   (00:13)
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-22-generi Mon Dec 27 21:13 - 21:27  (00:14)
ben      tty1                          Mon Dec 27 21:11 - down   (00:01)
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-22-generi Mon Dec 27 21:11 - 21:13  (00:01)
ben      tty1                          Mon Dec 27 21:10 - down   (00:01)
reboot   system boot  5.13.0-22-generi Mon Dec 27 21:09 - 21:11  (00:01)
```

Here is also a snippet from `/var/log/syslog` at the point where the last reboot occurred. Note the time 02:28:15, which is where messages occur that are typical of a reboot.

```
Dec 28 22:17:01 ben-server CRON[35367]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 28 22:17:11 ben-server 50-motd-news[35384]:  * Super-optimized for small spaces - read how we shrank the memory
Dec 28 22:17:11 ben-server 50-motd-news[35384]:    footprint of MicroK8s to make it the smallest full K8s around.
Dec 28 22:17:11 ben-server 50-motd-news[35384]:    https://ubuntu.com/blog/microk8s-memory-optimisation
Dec 28 22:17:11 ben-server systemd[1]: motd-news.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 28 22:17:11 ben-server systemd[1]: Finished Message of the Day.
Dec 28 22:53:36 ben-server systemd[5122]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-be17dd72dbdf5028d9e099ff548b2e4bf9b6f9f1c13d90bbfc288643354606c3-runc.zBfpwj.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 28 23:17:01 ben-server CRON[45621]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 28 23:33:14 ben-server systemd[5122]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-be17dd72dbdf5028d9e099ff548b2e4bf9b6f9f1c13d90bbfc288643354606c3-runc.ec7o7k.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 29 00:00:00 ben-server systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
Dec 29 00:00:00 ben-server systemd[1]: Starting Daily man-db regeneration...
Dec 29 00:00:00 ben-server systemd[1]: logrotate.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 29 00:00:00 ben-server systemd[1]: Finished Rotate log files.
Dec 29 00:00:00 ben-server systemd[1]: man-db.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 29 00:00:00 ben-server systemd[1]: Finished Daily man-db regeneration.
Dec 29 00:17:01 ben-server CRON[57015]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 29 00:22:54 ben-server systemd[1]: Starting Ubuntu Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs...
Dec 29 00:22:54 ben-server systemd[1]: ua-timer.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 29 00:22:54 ben-server systemd[1]: Finished Ubuntu Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs.
Dec 29 01:17:02 ben-server CRON[68356]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 29 01:49:42 ben-server systemd[5122]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-be17dd72dbdf5028d9e099ff548b2e4bf9b6f9f1c13d90bbfc288643354606c3-runc.1C5L9z.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 29 02:17:01 ben-server CRON[79961]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 29 02:21:48 ben-server systemd[5122]: run-docker-runtime\x2drunc-moby-be17dd72dbdf5028d9e099ff548b2e4bf9b6f9f1c13d90bbfc288643354606c3-runc.pvjfl1.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd-modules-load[424]: Inserted module 'msr'
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Finished Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Finished Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: modprobe@configfs.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module configfs.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: modprobe@fuse.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module fuse.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Finished Set the console keyboard layout.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Modules.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Finished Uncomplicated firewall.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Activating swap /swap.img...
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Rebuild Hardware Database being skipped.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Platform Persistent Storage Archival being skipped.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Activated swap /swap.img.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Finished Load/Save Random Seed.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in First Boot Complete being skipped.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd[1]: Finished Apply Kernel Variables.
```

I didn't see a reason that was obvious to me that the system rebooted, though I did find further evidence in the log that I believe means the reboot was unexpected:

```
Dec 29 02:28:15 ben-server systemd-fsck[636]: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt
```

I feel if it was a bad disk I would have seen some kernel errors. I'm now thinking the most likely culprit is the PSU? I currently have it plugged into a UPS, but I know that obviously won't fix a faulty unit.

Anyone have any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Test the psu or your whole machine with `stress` testing. Test full load, idle, full load, idle, perhaps you can force the shutdown. Faulty ram or other hardware components can also be an issue. Sometimes you can only find the broken hardware by replacing one by one and test inbetween

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt many people will have the issue that I ultimately found. Per the comment by @AlexOnLinux, I tried stress testing the computer and that is when I was having issues. I figured it must be the PSU, but when I went to check the power connection, I noticed that when I touched the power cable, the system immediately shutdown.

I then got a meter out to test continuity of the cable as I was flexing it and, sure enough, the connection broke many times. I replaced the cable and haven't had an issue since!